# Magento2 - Get category URL by ID

Tags: magento2, url, magento-2.1, category-attribute, url-key

I'm trying to get the URL key of any given category with the ID. I have this;

```
$categoryId = 3;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
print_r($object_manager->getData());
```

And this works (in the print_r there is the URL key I need), but category #3 is the top-level category. Whenever I try any subcategory (say ID 5) I get a blank array.
I'm just lost for words, can't figure it out.

In Magento 1.x I used to do this: `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catID)->getUrl()` and that worked.

**TL;DR:** This code works, change the ID to a (correct) category ID and change `getData()` to `getUrl()` for the complete category url, or `getName()` for the category name.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In order to get the category url you need to use the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` function `getUrl()` like so:

```
$category->getUrl()
```

Also, you can  get url by `CategoryRepositoryInterface`

```
nameSpace ['Your_nameSpace'] 
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
class ['Your_Class_name']
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $categoryRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    ) {
        .........
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

     public  function getCategory()
    {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        return $category->getUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Changing getData to getUrl was the right call.

Comment: Working fine, Up voted for you

Comment: please keep in mind that the mehtod `getUrl` is _not_ defined in the `CategoryInterface` which is defined as returnValue of the repository's `get` method. While this will work in most situatons, it is still not guaranteed to do so.

Answer (score 13):

Always try to use repository. You need to inject following way:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
 */
protected $categoryHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
 */
protected $categoryRepository;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,

) {
    $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}
```

For category url

```
$categoryId = 3;
$categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
echo  $this->categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($categoryObj);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was attempting to loop through IDs with the CategoryModel which was reloading the same data through iterations. You saved me after a bunch of head scratching!

Answer (score 8):

You can try below code.

```
$categoryId = 5;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($object_manager->getData());
```

Before you use a category id you have confirm category id exists in admin or it will return an empty array.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Uh yeah, that's the exact code I wrote in the OP. But you are correct, I tried on some ID's that I thought existed, but didn't.

Comment: I'd avoid using the Object manager (Plenty of resources online to suggest why). Also would advise that variables are also named appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

If you care about performance, this is a light Model that you can inject and use.

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ModuleNamespace\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class GetCategoryUrlByCategoryId
{
    /**
     * @var UrlFinderInterface
     */
    private $urlFinder;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
    ) {
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param string | int $categoryId
     * @param null $storeId
     * @return string
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function execute($categoryId, $storeId = null): string
    {
        /** @var Store $store */
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);

        /** @var UrlRewrite $rewrite */
        $rewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData(
            [
                UrlRewrite::ENTITY_ID => $categoryId,
                UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
                UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $store->getId(),
            ]
        );

        if (!$rewrite) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(new Phrase('Url rewrite does not exist for category ID "%1".', [$categoryId]));
        }

        return $store->getUrl('', ['_direct' => $rewrite->getRequestPath()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on my custom block (using category repository and DI):

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
  // ...
) 
{
  $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
  // ...
}


/**
 * Return the category object by its id.
 * 
 * @param categoryId (Integer)
 */
public function getCategory($categoryId)
{
  return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}


/**
 * Category repository object
 */
protected $_categoryRepository;
```

Finally, within a template file I just use:

```
$this->getCategory(3)->getUrl()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I need category urls from different domains (per store view), I had to create a new Url object per store view.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;

class CacheWarmer
{
    /** @var CollectionFactory */
    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface */
    protected $storeManager;

    /** @var UrlFactory */
    protected $urlFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory
    )
    {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlFactory = $urlFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores();

        foreach ($stores as $store) {

            $this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($store);

            $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();

            $urlCreator = $this->urlFactory->create();

            /** @var Category $category */
            foreach ($collection as $category) {

                $requestPath = $category->getRequestPath();
                if (!$requestPath) {
                    continue;
                }

                $url = $urlCreator->getDirectUrl($category->getRequestPath());

                $result = @file_get_contents($url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@andrea Please update getCategory method. Either it works well.

```php
/**
 * Return the category object by its id.
 * 
 * @param categoryId (Integer)
 */
public function getCategory($categoryId)
{
  return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}
```