# How to Check a catagory is Anchored or non Anchored Programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, magento-catalog

I want to check whether my current category in Anchored in Magneto 2

Comment: please explain briefly what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @RkRathod if want to check wethermy current catagory layout in `catalog_category_view_type_default` or `catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children`

Comment: where you actually want to implement this thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments and requriement mentioned you can try the below logic:
Through Objectmanager:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$xmlLayout = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\View::class);
$loadedHandles = $xmlLayout->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
```

Through class injection:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface $view
){
    $this->view = $view;
}
```

Use the below code to get loaded handles:

```
$loadedHandles = $this->view->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
```

For **isAnchored** you will get below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => default
    [1] => catalog_category_view
    [2] => catalog_category_view_type_layered
    [3] => catalog_category_view_type_layered_without_children
    [4] => catalog_category_view_id_4
)
```

And for **Non-Anchored** you will get below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => default
    [1] => catalog_category_view
    [2] => catalog_category_view_type_default
    [3] => catalog_category_view_id_20
    [4] => catalog_category_view_layout_update_680a89c63ad8009fef6e1a9900eab84e
)
```

You can now use php in_array function to check your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Pass category ID as per your requirement :

```
$categoryId = 17;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($object_manager->getData());
```

**Note : Use of objectManager is not good idea. Instead of this you can use DI.**

Check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/130019/49826)

> 1 = Is Anchor  0 = Not Anchor

Comment: if want to check wether layout in `catalog_category_view_type_default` or `catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children`

Comment: Dude its different question. You must have mentioned this in question.

Comment: should i post a different question??

Answer (score 2):

```
private $categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
) {
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
}

public function getCategoryAnchor() {
    $categoryId = '15'; // your category id
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);

    if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
        // your custom code
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
As per your requirements, i think you need to find out the current layout used for current category, so try the below code :

**If you are using .phtml file**

then use

> $block->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getPageLayout()

**If you are using block class**

> $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getPageLayout()

Comment: if want to check wether layout in catalog_category_view_type_default or catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: i want to to check wether this catagory is anchored or not.. but i want this through its layout name  i searched for a while and found that anchored categories load `catalog_category_view_type_default` layout how can i do this??

Comment: check my edited answer, if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can check using Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory as follows:

```
protected $_category;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $category
) {
    $this->_category = $category;
}

public function execute() {
    $category = $this->_category->create()->load($id);
    var_dump($category->getIsAnchor()); // string "0" or "1"
}
```

Comment: if want to check wether layout in catalog_category_view_type_default or catalog_category_view_type_default_without_children