# Magento 2 : How to get category data by category id?

Tags: magento2, product, category, collection

I have product object & i get category ids using

```
$category_id = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

I need the collection for the category ids which i get in `$category_id`
What will be the best & optimized way to get it in (block or helper  or model) ?

Thanks

Comment: This link provide your answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130011/magento2-get-category-url-by-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the category collection factory for getting the category.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
    ) {
            $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getCategoryCollection()
    {
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds);
    }
```

Let me know still if you face any queries.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will i get category name also on $collection->getName() ?

Comment: Yes definitely. You can also refer to this blog: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-categories-specific-product-magento-2.html

Comment: @dev if the answer is helpful then please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a Block and add following code:

```
<?php
namespace vendor\Category\Block;

class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /* $categoryId as category id */
    public function getCategoryById($categoryId){
        try {
            return $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return ['response' => 'Category Not Found'];
        }
    }
}
```

2)Create custom template and add following code:

```
$categoryId = 5; // category id
$getCategory = $block->getCategoryById($categoryId);
echo $getCategory->getName();echo "<br>";
echo $getCategory->getUrlKey();echo "<br>";
echo $getCategory->getIsActive();echo "<br>";
echo "<pre>";print_r($getCategory->getData());
```