# Magento 2 - Custom Product Attribute Category Model

Tags: magento2.4, magento-product-attributes

Upgrading an M1 site that uses the following function to output a link to a custom product attribute collection.  Can someone help me with the proper way to do this in M2?  Thanks!

```
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();

addSeriesLinkToMsg($cats);


/**
 * @param $cats
 *
 * @return string
 */
function addSeriesLinkToMsg($cats)
{
    if (in_array(SERIES_CAT, $cats))
    {
        //Loop through all categories and find the furthest down
        $series_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(SERIES_CAT);
        foreach ($cats as $cat)
        {
            $my_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);

            if (stristr($my_cat->getPath(), "/" . SERIES_CAT . "/") && $my_cat->getLevel() > $series_cat->getLevel())
            {
                $series_cat = $my_cat;
            }

        }

        //Only display the message if the series category isn't the root
        if ($series_cat->getId() != SERIES_CAT)
        {
            return "Series: <a href=\"" . $series_cat->getUrl() . "\">" . $series_cat->getName() . "</a>";
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code:

> public function __construct(
> \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
> ) {
> $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
> }
> $series_cat = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load(SERIES_CAT);

// Here one more loop with same code you can require if same child levels which was in M1

> foreach($cats as $cat){
> $my_cat = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($cat);
> }

**NOTE:**  Use Factory Type as I mentioned above it will create new object every time like getModel() in M1.

See below link for more [load category by ID useinng DI and Object Manager](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130011/magento2-get-category-url-by-id)